# console.error in react-native throws red screen even when __DEV__ is false

Tags: javascript, react-native, exponentjs

I'm building react-native app with Exponent and do some logging with `console.error` e.g. when network request fails etc. While it's helpful in development to see this red screen with error on simulator or real device, I'm getting this too when `__DEV__` is set to `false` (seeing it is set so in logs) while the web says it shouldn't work like this.

How can I disable that for non-dev builds? Is there any other way than monkey-patching `console.error`?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this fullscreen error until you run your app in production mode. That means you need to run your iOS/Android app in production.

If you want to do it with iOS you need to change your Scheme to `Release`

More details can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)

Comment: Thanks! But I don't get what does `__DEV__` really do? Because it seems like there are three different types of how app can behave: dev (with `__DEV__===true`, prod (with `Release` scheme) as you suggest and something in between (`__DEV__===false` but not `Release`) which is kind of crazy ;)

Comment: `__DEV__` can be used to run code pieces if it's you are developing or running the app in production. If you set your xcode to `Release`, `__DEV__` will be also false.
You should avoid to use `console.error` then. Probably you can switch to `console.warn`.

This will result in a `yellowbox` which can be disabled
More infos [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#warnings)

Comment: the console.error can break a production build somehow??? its very helpfull in developement, but iam afraid to break it in production. Cant find any docs about it

Comment: I didn't know that console.error throw an error in dev mode. I was struggling, trying to search where the throw comes from... Now I'm aware of that, thanks god ! haha

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer by Tobias Lins, for the sake of completeness.

You can also use the following, both in prod and debug builds:

```js
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

// Ignore on a per-message basis
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: ReactNative.createElement is deprecated…']);

// Ignore all
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
```